# Error: Convert Drawable To Bitmap Inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

Hi I am populating a custom listview from parse user table. In that if the row doesn't containing a image I want to show one local image. For that I need to convert the drawable image into bitmap inside a fragment. I tried couple of methods. But none work and I don't know what is the error.

And my code is...

```
postImage = po.getParseFile("pic");
                            if (postImage != null && postImage.getUrl() != null && postImage.getUrl().length() > 0) {
                                postImage.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                        people.setPic(bmp);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.sanjay);
                                Log.d("ImageCoversion", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.sanjay).toString());
                                people.setPic(icon);
                            }
```

I am getting error in getActivity().getResources() inside else block.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

And my full doInBackground code is

```
protected List<People> doInBackground(List<People>... params) {

        try {

            final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    ParseFile image = null;

                    if (e == null) {

                        peopleList.clear();

                        obj = objects;
                        for (ParseObject po : objects) {

                            //image = (ParseFile) po.get("pic");
                            ParseFile postImage;

                            final People people = new People();

                            people.setName(po.getString("username"));
                            people.setLastMessage(po.getString("email"));
                            people.setObjectId(po.getObjectId());

                            //people.setProfilePic(image.getUrl());

                            postImage = po.getParseFile("pic");
                            if (postImage != null && postImage.getUrl() != null && postImage.getUrl().length() > 0) {
                                postImage.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                        people.setPic(bmp);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.sanjay);
                                Log.d("ImageCoversion", icon.toString());
                                people.setPic(icon);

                            }
                            peopleList.add(people);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("*****Error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return peopleList;
    }
```

Comment: Try to load the Bitmap once on startup and reuse it. It will be better for performance and you will have the guarantee that you have access to the Activity resources at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring `Activity a = getActivity();` at the beginning of your code

In this else instead of : 

`Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.sanjay);`

use :

`Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), R.drawable.sanjay);`

Sometimes getActivity() returns null.

Comment: Can you please show me where exactly have you implemented the getActivity()?

Comment: public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {
Activity mActivity;
.......
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }
}

Comment: Actually I want you to put it public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {} between the braces after inflating the layout a= getActivity();

Comment: @SanjayAD anytime. Happy coding.